# Strange Border Radius issue in IE11

Tags: html, css, sass, storybook

I'm having a strange issue with IE11 border radiuses:
[image: IE11 Border Radius]

The code is

```
.xrInput__input {
  border: 2px solid $xr-dark-blue;
  border-radius: $xr-border-radius;
  background-color: $xr-white;

  font-family: var(--font-crimson-text);
  font-size: 1rem;
  order: 2;
  padding: map-get($xr-spacing, 'xs');
  transition: border-color 200ms ease-out;

  &:focus {
    border-color: $xr-warm-yellow;
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

I've added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the Storybook `preview-head.html` as well as tried other methods such `background-clip: padding-box;` which have been mentioned to no avail.

Has anyone come across a solution to this.

I've also got Autoprefixer in place but it shouldnt be needed for IE11.

Working example here: https://deploy-preview-11--xr-theme.netlify.com/?path=/story/forms-input--input

Comment: I run a genuine IE11 and i see no bugs loading https://deploy-preview-11--xr-theme.netlify.com/?path=/info/forms-input--input

Comment: Must be one of those strange Virtual Box things then, thanks :)